# Save as 8bit PNG

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating placeholder images in certain sizes that will be used as Data URIs

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 10);
```

I have done some research, but can't find a good way of saving this bitmap as the smallest possible filesize, which is why I want an 8bit PNG.

My question is: How can I save this bitmap into a file/bytearray/stream as an 8bit PNG? Any good libraries?

Comment: Leadtools has a good library to deal with bitmaps.

Comment: Hm couldnt you use a better solution for this? Why do you need bitmaps?

Comment: @Vajura you are right. I don't need to use bitmaps. All I need is a transparent PNG of low file size.

Comment: But why do you need it? Are they gonna be invisible buttons where later you are gonna place pictures under them?

Comment: I am loading responsive images via Javascript, but I need the transparent placeholder image to have the same aspect ratio to prevent page jumping

Comment: Hm, so you are dynamicly placing <img> objects? Cant you force set the size without any actualy image in it?

Comment: No because it has to be responsive. width = 100%; height = auto;

Comment: Ah sry was imagining the wrong thing then. Then if thats your only solution, for a transparent png of any width/height you can use photoshop to set it at the lowest size absolutly possible

Comment: I need this to be done dynamically. I have already coded this solution in Java, but for C# I am simply missing a simple library that can convert an indexed PNG

Comment: I like the FreeImage library available on: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeimage/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **nQuant** ([which you can install with nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nQuant/), or see references below). The following example converts an image on disk and would be readily adapted to meet your needs.

```
    public static bool TryNQuantify(string inputFilename, string outputFilename)
    {
        var quantizer = new nQuant.WuQuantizer();
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(inputFilename);
        if (bitmap.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        {
            ConvertTo32bppAndDisposeOriginal(ref bitmap);
        }

        try
        {
            using (var quantized = quantizer.QuantizeImage(bitmap))
            {
                quantized.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void ConvertTo32bppAndDisposeOriginal(ref Bitmap img)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
        img.Dispose();
        img = bmp;
    }
```

For more information see:

- https://github.com/mcychan/nQuant.cs
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Convert-32-bit-PNGs-to-81ef8c81

Comment: This worked fine to me, however it's important to note that when I dealt with images that had height bigger than 4550 pixels it failed to generate image and the output was an empty gray image.

Answer (score 0):

I like the FreeImage project, it is light weight and easy to use. Below is an example of creating a transparent png. You could easily wrap this in a method and set the width and height and transparency value.

```
//create a new bit map
FIBITMAP dib = new FIBITMAP();

//allocate a 16x10 bitmap with 8bit depth
dib = FreeImage.Allocate(16, 10, 8);

//set the transpareny
byte[] Transparency = new byte[1];
Transparency[0] = 0x00;
FreeImage.SetTransparencyTable(dib, Transparency);

//save the bitmap
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, dib, "C:\\temp\\tp.png", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I tried using FreeImage. Added it with nuget, but couldn't find it in my project.

Comment: Try it the old fashioned way. Download from http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html add the freeimagenet.dll as a reference and copy freeimage.dll to your build folder.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a small transparent image, why stop at 8 bit? You can go straight down to 1 bit! You only need one colour anyway, and it'll be even smaller.

In fact, you don't even need to do anything special for that. Since the pixels on a new indexed bitmap will all default to 0, meaning they reference its first palette colour, all you need to do is make a new 1bpp image, and set that first palette colour to transparent:

```
public static Bitmap MakePlaceholderImage(Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
    // This colour can't be assigned directly since the .Palette getter actually makes a copy of the palette.
    ColorPalette pal = bm.Palette;
    pal.Entries[0] = Color.Transparent;
    bm.Palette = pal;
    return bm;
}
```

I experimented a bit with this, and, saved as png, the end result seemed to consistently be 8 times smaller than the result of the same code executed with 8bpp. For a 5000x5000 image, the file size as png was barely over 3 KiB.

Answer (score 0):

Google search led me to a 6 year old thread and I can't find my solution. It should've been possible 6 years as well, as it uses the System.Drawing Libraray of the .Net Framework.

This example code should help anyone who want to write an 8 bit indexed png.

```
static class SaveImages
{
    public static void SaveGrayImage(Bitmap srcImg, string name)
    {
        Bitmap grayImg = new Bitmap(srcImg.Width, srcImg.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        var pal = grayImg.Palette;
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 256))
            pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
        grayImg.Palette = pal;

        var data = grayImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, srcImg.Width, srcImg.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        var bytes = new byte[data.Stride * data.Height];
        foreach (int y in Enumerable.Range(0, srcImg.Height))
        {
            foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(0, srcImg.Width))
            {
                var colour = srcImg.GetPixel(x, y);
                var c = (int)colour.R + (int)colour.G + (int)colour.B;
                c /= 3;
                bytes[data.Stride * y + x] = (byte)c;
            }
        }

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);
        grayImg.Save(name, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Edit: To add transparency dabble with the color palette.

Answer (score -1):

1) Create your bitmap with 8 bit per pixel format:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(20, 20, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

See [PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more formats.

2) Draw to the bitmap ...

3) Then save it as PNG:

```
bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\xyz.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

The created file will have the same pixel format as `bmp` (8 bit)

Comment: This doesn't support transparency it seems, and it also creates a very large file size.

Comment: The format `Format8bppIndexed` of course does not support transparency, I just used this for the example, use the format that fit your needs, look at the `PixelFormat` enum. As always on SO, never just copy/paste code, use the it as hint and improve it to your needs.

Comment: None of the indexed ones here support transparency. Transparency is essential for my placeholder images.

Comment: Both PNG and GIF support transparency with indexed images.  You have to make sure the pallet for your bitmap has the transparent color included.

Comment: Step 2) in this explanation will be problematic; 8-bit images cannot be drawn on with standard functions. You need to access/extract the backing array with `LockBits` to manipulate it.